# query for words between two tag <h3></h3>

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

in need a query that search my word between two tag

like

```
<h3>ali</h3>
hasan ali
<h3>ali kamali</h3>
```

When user search ali I need,

```
 <h3>ali</h3>
 <h3>ali kamali</h3>
```

[image]

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: i use android studio .please see my tags!

Comment: @kNeerajLal i dont have any query, i want a query!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   mytable 
WHERE
   field LIKE '<h3>%' + query + '%</h3>'
```

See [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/73200/1) fiddle for a working sample.

[image: SQL Fiddle]

Comment: this does not work correctly and return "hasan ali" alos becuse hasan ali is between <h3> ali and  kamali</h3>

Comment: oh no no!, all '<h3>ali</h3>
hasan ali
<h3>ali kamali</h3>' is in a record:
http://uupload.ir/files/42ep_asd.png